# googlesheets gives old or cached data when downloading with curl

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I'm using this url to download a googlesheet programmatically `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{SHEET_ID}/export?gid=0&format=csv`

For some reason every once in a while it gives old data, like 1 week old or something. This is completely random. Sometimes it even shows fresh data, and goes back to old data the next request.

The sheet in question is public but importing data from a private sheet like this

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET_ID", "sheet!A:Z"), "SELECT * WHERE Col1 LIKE '%keyword%'", 1)
```

The private sheet is also importing data from another sheet. Anything I can do to prevent this seemingly non-deterministic bug?

Comment: it only happens with that sheet importing the data with the other ones ? or it's also happening with other sheets?

Comment: @albertovielma no clue, I can't reproduce the issue, it happens randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Similar behaviour observed with a published sheet which is designed to show time and a live schedule. "Recalculate every minute" setting didn't help. Solution is to put some value into a cell with a script. The script is set to run every minute.

```
function Somechanges() {
  var someValue = Math.random();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('J1').activate();
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(someValue);
};
```