# ImportRange showing different values than parent sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Several of our sheets have started to show different values than their parent sheets. It only happens when the number is driven by a formula. The sheets themselves "should" be identical though
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICtBN.png). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX5P2.png)

An example is below. The source sheet and the sheet that it is importing to are showing different values throughout the entire sheet. They should be the same, but as an example the source file for example on Medellin Total Total Shared Bedrooms Available for August is 12. The file it's imported in says 11.

I made sure the data format was the same, I made sure the time format was the same, I tried to limit the size of both spreadsheets. I've ensured it's not just a data lag either.

Comment: instead of telling what text and date to look for, it will be far easier for us to find what you are talking about if you also gave the cell references including the column letter and the row number.

Comment: As a matter of interest, do the figures update if you "refresh" the target page?

Comment: Apologies Mr. Shane. AB12 and AB23 are 2 examples where the data should be identical (it's just an importrange). 

Tedinoz - I've refreshed the target and source page. The only way the import page actually shows the correct value is if I take out the formula I used on the source page and paste it at values. Then it immediately changes to the correct value on the target. It changes to the wrong value again though when I put the formula back in.

Comment: I'm thinking "cache" problem (though without having any thought of a specific solution). OTOH, `the formula I used on the source page`; this does seem relevant. Would you please describe the formula.

Comment: I'm clutching at straws here but have you read [googlesheets gives old or cached data when downloading with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70243522/1330560). The answer hasn't had an upvote but I thought you might care to try it.

Comment: The formulas on the source page are either sumifs or simple subtraction formulas. Good to know on that thread with the script solution. I would assume if that worked though so would just editing the formula and having it run again (this didn't fix the solution before).

I ultimately removed a bunch of data from the source and destination spreadsheets so they're more bare-boned now. The issue seems to be solved, but it's frustrating knowing it might pop up again.